# Select Element onChange event is not firing?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a select element with an onChange event that *does* fire when I click the select box and select a new value within it. But, when I tab to the select box and press the up or down arrows to change the select box's value, the event does not fire.

I am using `jQuery().change(function(){ ... });` to set the event

Comment: ehh, you need to press `return` in order to make a "change".

Comment: It doesn't change the value until the `blur` event happens.

Comment: Try combining it with the click event, I think that may fire in that case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you tab into a `<select>` element, the change event doesn't fire until you press the Enter key.

Comment: Turns out, this is the problem. I just used the `bindWithDelay` jQuery plugin to have it change on keyup after a delay.

Answer (score 1):

For an `onChange()` to fire the value must be changed *and* the `input` must be `blur()`-ed (focus moved elsewhere); which is why it fires in your first case, but not in the second.

> The change event is sent to an element when its value changes. This event is limited to `<input>` elements, `<textarea>` boxes and `<select>` elements. For select boxes, checkboxes, and radio buttons, the event is fired immediately when the user makes a selection with the mouse, but for the other element types the event is deferred until the element loses focus.

Reference:

- [`change()`](http://api.jquery.com/change/).

Answer (score 1):

As others have stated, the change event doesn't happen until the blur event. You'll need to monitor keyup as well to capture someone moving changing the values with the arrow keys.

Monitor keyup and change,

```
$('select').bind('change keyup', function() {
   // Handle
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/robert/Je26w/

Answer (score 1):

You can trigger the `blur` event on `keyup` on the `select` and then give back `focus`, which will trigger the change:

```
$('select').keyup(function(){
  $(this).blur().focus();
});
```

example: http://jsfiddle.net/niklasvh/XEg36/

Comment: This did not give me back focus in FireFox. But this works:

`$('select').keyup(function(){
  $(this).trigger("change");
});`